# Return value from a stream when it is completed Flutter

Tags: flutter, websocket, stream

I have a WebSocket stream. I have a function named sendMessage() that sends a message throug a websocket and returns the request of the websocket server. Problem is that my function is returning null because returns before websocket's streams has been completed.

1. Don't know how to call senMessage() so that it waits for websocket
   stream to be completed.
2. Don't know how to write senMessage() so that it returns only when websocket streams has            been completed

Calling sendMessage() in my code:

String aux = await sendMessage(jsonString,device_ip,'199');

```
Future <String> sendMessage(msg, String ip, String port)  async {
  WebSocketChannel? channel;
  // We use a try - catch statement, because the connection might fail.
    try {
      // Connect to our backend.
      channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse('ws://${ip}:${port}'));
    } catch (e) {
      // If there is any error that might be because you need to use another connection.
      print("Error on connecting to websocket: " + e.toString());
    }

  // Send message to backend
  channel?.sink.add(msg);
  String? aux;

  // Listen for any message from backend

  channel?.stream.listen((response) {
    // Just making sure it is not empty
    if (response!.isNotEmpty) {
      // Now only close the connection and we are done here!
      if(response!="Connected"){
        aux=response;
        channel!.sink.close();
      }
    }

  }, onDone: ()  {

    print("Stream done");});

  return aux.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to 'await' for the request to finish using the **await** keyword. Do this instead: 
 `channel = await WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse('ws://${ip}:${port}'));`

Comment: Thanks, but compiler error with this line "error: Missing selector such as '.identifier' or '[0]". I tried instead with: 
channel = await WebSocketChannel.connect(Uri.parse('ws://${ip}:${port}'));
But function keeps returning null

Comment: Sorry for that! It should say channel = await... <br> Though, it returns null because **aux** is nullable and it is in fact null in the end because you only give it a value when the response is different than 'Connected'.